# Most "Airflownic" way of getting list for generating tasks

Tags: dynamic, airflow

I have a list of names that I use to generate dynamic tasks in my DAG file as follow:

```
ops = []
for table in list_of_names:
    dw = SnowflakeOperator(task_id=table)
    ops.append(dw)
```

My question is: what is the most "Airflownic" way of getting the list among the following? (taking into account that there should not be any top code in the DAG file)

```
list_of_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ... 'z']

list_of_names = list(Variable.get('list_of_names'))

with open('list_of_names.txt', 'r') as list_file:
    list_of_names = list_file.read()
```

Comment: Do you really need only names in a specific sequence or your case is actually different? If these are really name in sequence you can create them with a simple python loop no need for a pre defined list.

Comment: I don't need a specific sequence but the list is huge (10 lines of hardcoded names),  so I prefer to pre-define it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> list_of_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ... 'z']

I vote for that one. Pythonic, nice, fast, no need to add extra "entities".

> list_of_names = list(Variable.get('list_of_names'))

Very bad. If you have your variable in DB it will query the DB every time scheduler parses the file (which might be every 60 s. or so).

> with open('list_of_names.txt', 'r') as list_file:
> list_of_names = list_file.read()

2nd best (or rather 2nd worst). I actually do not see it as Pythonic at all. Separation of "list of tasks" and DAG to create it makes very little sense. They are conceptually part of the same definition of the DAG. Unless you want to use that list in other places/DAGs, there is no point in separating them.

And even if you have such need, there is no need to have a separate ".txt" or other "declarative" way to define those. We are in the world of Python. We already need to import and parse Python code. Importing an ARRAY from another python module, is so much better than reading it from a .txt file. I'd vote in such case for another solution:

```
from my_org.common_definitions import MY_TASKS

ops = []
for table in MY_TASKS:
    dw = SnowflakeOperator(task_id=table)
    ops.append(dw)
```

Having a separate file in txt, or (say) json-array if you need more attributes, might be only justified if you have some process that for example will dump those regularly to the file. However even then, it would be more "airflowy" and "pythonic" to produce an importable Python file with the array  defined as python constant to import (if only you could easily control the format of this file).